# Google and others are phasing out support of Adobe Flash. Will this affect applications made with Apache Flex

Tags: apache, flash, apache-flex, web-applications, adobe

Adobe Flex is perfect for an application we sell. However we want to move this application to a server and have users access it online rather than having their own copy.

Adobe Flex and Flash are unsupported on android and from the looks of it this lack of support will spread.

Will this affect the use of our application if we build it with Apache Flex?

EDIT:
The primary and most important function or our application is an excel style table that is part of a form. This table allows the user to input the details of the floors of an office building. It has set columns (floor, population etc) then as many rows as the user requires.

Comment: You should describe the nature of your application so others can confirm if it's do-able via browser code only (JavaScript, PHP, etc). As for Android, Flash can compile the AS3/Flex code to Android's APK format but this means mobile users have to buy/install your app (the unwanted _"...having their own copy"_ issue). Also some mobile browsers (Puffin, Dolphin, etc) can display Flash content in web pages. Don't know how , but who says Google isn't perfecting their own trick for future desktop/mobile browser versions? Firefox and others have experimentally displayed SWF (Flash) using JS only..

Comment: @VC.One thanks for the tip! Post updated.
Thanks for all that info. Sounds like for now if it Flex does require flash then it's not the tool for us.